# How to make a site's content stick in the middle?

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

In HTML, how do you make it so that the site is ~60-80% of the screen wide, and if the window is bigger than that it centers, otherwise there's a scroll bar? I'm talking about the way it is for the content here at StackOverflow.

I tried this, but failed:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div style="width: 60em; align: center;">kdsjlglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgkhlglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgklglkdfjgolksdjflgojsdfsdoljfglsdfghsdkjfgkdhfgkkjdghkdsfjgksdjfhg</div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the one I always follow:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        your content
    </div>
</body>
```

And then in CSS,

```
body{text-align:center;}
.wrapper{width:80%;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;}
```

Comment: Throw in a text-align:left; into .wrapper if needed and you're gold with this - all the other answers will just be different flavours of this one :)

Comment: Set the min-width property, too, so when the browser is small the content stops shrinking.

Answer (score 2):

You want auto margins...

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    Your page content here...
  </div>
</body>
```

Your CSS should have something like this...

```
#content { width: 60%; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
```

The ordering for margins (and padding is the same) is top right bottom left. Or you can shortcut with.

```
#content { width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This means that top and bottom will have 0 margin; left and right will have auto margin.

Answer (score 1):

- Do [Set left and right margins to `auto`](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#block).
- Don't use the **deprecated** `<center>` element
- Don't use the non-existent `align` property

Answer (score 1):

Stick your content in a div and set the right and left margin to "auto", like so:

CSS:

```
#content {
 width:        960px;
 margin-left:  auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="content">
 fjkgjkg etc.
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That div isn't floated, nor does it need to be.